# buildozer version apk googleplay not changed

Tags: google-play, kivy, buildozer

I change my version in code

```
___version____ = "1.xx.xx"
```

But Google Play say me: Version old 100.
Why?
How can i change version apk with kivy buildozer?

Answer (score 0):

To change your apk's version you should specify in your `buildozer.spec` file:
`version=1.xx.xx`
Or use the second method:

```
version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
version.filename = (source.dir)s/your_file_with_version.py
```